# How to create infographics map with gradient scale to show spread of coronovirus by regions/countries?

Tags: r, maps, tableau-api

I know only one way which can create a map like this - using `tableau`.

But in **Tableau** you can map specific countries - not possible to map additionally regions with gradient scale . Need to customize background map  and map style -  add additional map layers and data layers.

[image]

In `Tableau`  possible to get  **Data Set** with **Latitudes** and **Longitudes** of interesting regions, but since scale in regions are different - one city can have one confirmed case - another city can have 1000 - I wanna use gradient scale.

[image]

My ideal map is a combination of these two examples.

Is there is any other software/frameworks which allow creating world map with a gradient scale of data inside the country?

and have direct access to regions inside the country as well?
Coz I want to connect it to software which parses news feed relates to a number of new cases in some city/district/country.

Instead of circles, I wanna show gradient scale of number of cases.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes, you can create a map similar to the one you show using various plotting routines in R. Provided you have geospatial data on a regional level (and provided you have shapefiles for those regions) you can draw that too. What *specifically* are you asking? Happy to help but please note that "can somebody show me code to do XYZ" is not a valid question.

Comment: I updated text in question - maybe now its clear that I want to have 3 different maps - by country/region and gradient scale inside the region.

Comment: Hi Tomka. Thanks for the update; but I still don't see a *specific* question. Nor do you provide any data/code. At the moment this reads a lot like "somebody please make this type of plot for me", which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you can provide some sample data and a code attempt (there are many *many* tutorials available on the web to get you started) I'm happy to help. Perhaps take a look at how to provide a good [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good place to start, using the `sf`, `rnaturalearth` packages.

```r
install.packages(c("cowplot", "googleway", "ggplot2", "ggrepel", 
                   "ggspatial", "libwgeom", "sf", "rnaturalearth", "rnaturalearthdata"))

library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")

library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("tidyverse")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)

corona <- readxl::read_excel('corona cases.xlsx', sheet = "Sheet1")

world$corona <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(corona)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(world)){

    country <- as.character(corona[i, 1])

    sov_rows <- which(world$sovereignt %in% country)

    world[sov_rows,"corona"] <- corona[i, 2]

  }

}

sov_rows <- which(world$sovereignt %in% "China")

world[sov_rows,"corona"] <- NA

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = corona)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for brief explanation!